Photon wave function spontaneous emission
Consider some atom that decays from an $L = 1$ state to an $L = 0$ state, thereby emitting a photon. What would the photon's spatial wave function look like? I myself have considered two options:

It would look like a $p$-wave because the photon would carry the atom's angular momentum, and that it has some finite radial width due to the energy-time uncertainty principle.

It would resemble a dipole radiation pattern.



The angular momentum is carried away by photon spin.

@my2cts I know, that is conservation of angular momentum. That is also the reason why I thought that it might be a $p$-wave.

I assume that by a p-wave you mean a wave with orbital angular momentum L=1.

@my2cts Ah yes did you mean that it might be an $s$-wave ($L = 0$) and that the angular momentum is in the spin of the photon?

Yes, indeed. Of course, such a wave is restricted to propagate (anti)parallel to its spin.

@my2cts Thanks! Now it makes sense to me.
